# How does Apache Storm store data

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have downloaded Apache Zookeeper and Apache Storm. And also extracted it in C drive. Now I want to know that how I will store data in it and process it with Storm? Like in previous I was using SQL server, and there I was saving the data in the software and getting the data from there by writing queries. But now I don't know where do I put data and access data. I have lots of text files and data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Storm is not a storage system but a stream processor. Thus, it reads input data from -- and writes output date to -- other systems. There is a bunch of provided connectors. See "Integration With External Systems, and Other Libraries" in https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/index.html

Furthermore, you can always implements custom source and sink operators by yourself.

As a side remark: if you have text files to process, I am not sure if a stream processing system is the right choice (it might be, depending on your use case). It seems, that a batch processing system is more suitable.